Pandas read csv that has multiple tables
I have a URL that downloads a csv file, to open it I am using the following code:
 df = pd.read_csv(url)

most URLs I am using only contain a single table and they open fine, but some have the following format which causes an error:

The csv file is divided into two tables by a set of two empty rows.
The code currently returns the following error:
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 9, saw 5

I am trying to read in both tables and then combine them into one table such as the following:


The csv file is divided into two tables by a set of two empty rows Sounds like you need to fix the csv file.

The URL is from an API, I do no control the API  so I cannot do that

Since each part of the file has a different number of rows, instead of loading it all at once, you can open it and split each part, read them with pandas.read_csv, then concat everything:
import pandas as pd
import io

path = 'file.csv'

with open(path, "r") as f:
    csv_list = f.read().split("\n\n\n")

df_list = [pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv)) for csv in csv_list]
df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)

If you want to download the file from a url, use a library like requests, then the rest is similar:
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io

url = "http://somehost/file.csv"

response = requests.get(url)
csv_list = response.text.split("\n\n\n")

df_list = [pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv)) for csv in csv_list]
df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)

Both will output:
    ID       date  Row A  Row B  Row C  Row D
0   10  7/29/2024      1    1.0    NaN    NaN
1   20  7/29/2024      2    2.0    NaN    NaN
2   30  7/29/2024      3    3.0    NaN    NaN
3   40  7/29/2024      4    4.0    NaN    NaN
4   50  7/29/2024      5    5.0    NaN    NaN
5   60  7/29/2024      1    NaN    1.0    1.0
6   70  7/29/2024      2    NaN    2.0    2.0
7   80  7/29/2024      3    NaN    3.0    3.0
8   90  7/29/2024      4    NaN    4.0    4.0
9  100  7/29/2024      5    NaN    5.0    5.0


I get the following error when Irun this code: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Have you changed the URL to your file location? That's the only reason why you'd get this error.

what file location? when I run the code the url variable is set as the url

@MustardTiger You have to download the file. Either download it manually and use the file path, or use a library like requests. I've update the answer with the second option too.

@e-motta provided a robust  and precise answer. Wrapping this code inside a function  with url parameter can be used in both cases: for single table csv or multiple table csv.
